# performance loss by running openMp algorithm in virtual machine

Tags: c++, macos, debian, openmp

Because I experienced problems compiling my openMp program on my mac, I started to compile and execute from my Debian virtual machine. It compiles fine and runs smoothly but I wonder if there may be disadvantages concerning the performance. It's a c++ code and I compile using g++.

Comment: When you create a VM you allow it to use a part of your host system resources. Thus performance of your program can be affect as you will for instance give  512MB RAM and one or two cores of your CPU to work with.

Comment: Yes, I know of that issue. But if I gave the VM 4 processors and enough RAM, can I expect the system to run as fast as doing the same calculations on the native system, using 4 processors?

Comment: You will have better performances, but it will never be as good as it could be on your host system as both your host system and your virtual machine use the same hardware and both need resources (to run programs, including your hypervisor). So it really depends what you do but performances in a VM can still be good enough...

Comment: With Virtual Box they don't recommend setting the number of cores to the number of hyper threads but to the number of physical cores. That may make a difference. I mean for example if you computer has 4 physical cores and 8 hyper-threads you should set the virtual machine to have 4 cores and not 8. I'm not sure if this matters. Until recently I would have used the number of hyper-threads but I think it may be a bad idea.

Comment: @Zboson, this is exactly, what i'm experienceing: with my dualcore machine, I get a linear speedup using only 2 threads and no more speedup using more threads. Do you have some link that explains this?

Comment: @Tom, I read it in the VirtualBox manual.

Comment: @Tom, the [Virtual Box manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor) says "You should not, however, configure virtual machines to use more CPU cores than you have available physically (real cores, no hyperthreads)".

Comment: @Zboson, Yes that makes sense now and I think, this is exactly what went wrong: I got the program to reach almost linear speedup on the university machines. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It was the last comment from Zboson that solves this: I used a dual core processor with up to eight hyperthreads and observed only linear speedup for two threads and not for any more. When I posted this questing I thought I had eight real cores.

Comment: What exactly is your processor (what does cat /proc/cpuinfo say)? Maybe you mean quad core? Hyper-threading only doubles the number of cores (although I think on the Xeon Phi cards it's different) so dual core would mean four hyper-threads (for a processor which has hyper-threading).

Comment: it is a dual core 2.8 GHz Intel Core i5

Comment: Many i5's (except some low powered ones for laptops) don't have HT. That's one of the main differences between an i5 and i7. Are you sure it even has hyper-threading?

Comment: I believe it has. it is a macbook pro (mid 2014)

Comment: It's a i5-4278U I think which has 2 cores and 4 hyper threads so not 8.

Comment: yes exactly. I was probably confused by VM offering me to up to eight CPUs

Comment: In anycase, it's interesting that VirtualBox says only to use the number of physical cores and not the number of hyper-threads. I wonder why this is.